# Xacro in-order processing for husky_gazebo

Tags: gazebo, husky, xacro

[image: Rosanswers logo]

After trying to run the following command

```
roslaunch husky_gazebo husky_playpen.launch
```

from this tutorial: http://wiki.ros.org/husky_navigation/Tutorials/Husky%20Frontier%20Exploration%20Demo

I encounter the following error:

```
... logging to /home/daniel/.ros/log/2e76d420-a6c4-11ea-afba-2390d77f85eb/roslaunch-daniel-Inspiron-7559-14421.log
Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take a while.
Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.
xacro: in-order processing became default in ROS Melodic. You can drop the option.
'bool' object has no attribute 'lower' 
when evaluating expression 'topbar_needed_kinect.lower() == 'true' or topbar_needed_kinect == '1' or topbar_needed_realsense == 'true' or topbar_needed_realsense == '1''

when processing file: /home/daniel/husky_ws/src/husky_description/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro
RLException: while processing /home/daniel/husky_ws/src/husky_gazebo/launch/spawn_husky.launch:
while processing /home/daniel/husky_ws/src/husky_control/launch/control.launch:
while processing /home/daniel/husky_ws/src/husky_description/launch/description.launch:
Invalid <param> tag: Cannot load command parameter [robot_description]: command [['/opt/ros/noetic/lib/xacro/xacro', '/home/daniel/husky_ws/src/husky_description/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro', '--inorder', 'robot_namespace:=/', 'laser_enabled:=true', 'kinect_enabled:=false', 'realsense_enabled:=false', 'urdf_extras:=']] returned with code [2]. 

Param xml is <param name="robot_description" command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find husky_description)/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro'     --inorder     robot_namespace:=$(arg robot_namespace)     laser_enabled:=$(arg laser_enabled)     kinect_enabled:=$(arg kinect_enabled)     realsense_enabled:=$(arg realsense_enabled)     urdf_extras:=$(arg urdf_extras)     "/>
The traceback for the exception was written to the log file
```

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/354092/xacro-in-order-processing-for-husky_gazebo/) by [ildaniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/55506/ildaniel/) on ROS Answers with karma: 25 on 2020-06-04

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi @ildaniel,

From ROS Melodic you do not need to include the `--inorder` option when launching Xacro, so you can drop it to avoid that warning:

```
<param name="robot_description"
   command="$(find xacro)/xacro '$(find husky_description)/urdf/husky.urdf.xacro' arg1:=... />
```

The last error is due to a lack of arguments, If you look at the value fetched into `urdf_extras` you will see that it is empty; this is because the value loaded through the launch file is trying to extract it from an enviroment variable that I am sure you did not set in your terminal:

```
<arg name="urdf_extras" default="$(optenv HUSKY_URDF_EXTRAS/>
```

If you look closely you will find it is the only argument in that launch [file](https://github.com/husky/husky/blob/melodic-devel/husky_description/launch/description.launch) which does not have a default value.

Try to export that variable ans see if that works

```
export HUSKY_URDF_EXTRAS=...
```

Cheers.

---

Originally posted by [Weasfas](https://answers.ros.org/users/34184/weasfas/) with karma: 1695 on 2020-06-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ildaniel](https://answers.ros.org/users/55506/ildaniel/) on 2020-06-05**:
Thanks for your response!  i removed the --inorder option and the urdf_extras because I don't want to customize the model now.  I also had to remove the .lower() from topbar_needed_kinect.lower() to loose the first error.